# Check if there is another Order for the same Customer in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database with a Customer Table and an Order table each order go to each Customer so what I want, is when the end user enters a new order for a Customer that has already an order, the user should get a msgbox that this Customer has an order already assigned to him.

So, how do I check if this Customer ID has an Order already?

I tried the DLookUp Function but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data in both tables, the `DLookup` code you already tried, and an explanation of how it "doesn't work", e.g. the expected results and your actual results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `dcount` function:

```
If dcount("customerID", "orders", "customerID=" & me.customerID) >0 then
   Msgbox "text"
End if
```